# How to scan through all the elements of a matrix with theano?

Tags: python, theano

#### TL;DR:

What is the `theano.scan` equivalent of:

```
M = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
for i in range(M.shape[0]):
    for j in range(M.shape[1]):
        M[i, j] += 5
M
```

*possibly* (if doable) without using nested `scan`s?

Note that this question does not want to be specifically about how to apply an operation elementwise to a matrix, but more generally on how to implement with `theano.scan` a nested looping construct like the above.

---

#### Long version:

`theano.scan` (or equivalently in this case, `theano.map`)  allows to map a function looping through multiple indices, by simply providing a sequence of elements to the `sequences` arguments, with something like

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
M = T.dmatrix('M')
def map_func(i, j, matrix):
    return matrix[i, j] + i * j
results, updates = theano.scan(map_func,
            sequences=[T.arange(M.shape[0]), T.arange(M.shape[1])],
            non_sequences=[M])
f = theano.function(inputs=[M], outputs=results)
f(np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3))
#
```

which is roughly equivalent to a python loop of the form:

```
M = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
for i, j in zip(np.arange(M.shape[0]), np.arange(M.shape[1])):
    M[i, j] += 5
M
```

which increases by 5 all the elements in the *diagonal* of `M`.

But what if I want to find the `theano.scan` equivalent of:

```
M = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
for i in range(M.shape[0]):
    for j in range(M.shape[1]):
        M[i, j] += 5
M
```

*possibly* without nesting `scan`?

One way is of course to `flatten` the matrix, `scan` through the flattened elements, and then `reshape` it to the original shape, with something like

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
M = T.dmatrix('M')
def map_func(i, X):
    return X[i] + .5
M_flat = T.flatten(M)
results, updates = theano.map(map_func,
                              sequences=T.arange(M.shape[0] * M.shape[1]),
                              non_sequences=M_flat)
final_M = T.reshape(results, M.shape)
f = theano.function([M], final_M)
f([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

but is there a better way that doesn't involve explicitly flattening and reshaping the matrix?

Comment: Is there any reason why you consider flatten to be a bad option? Notice that it only returns a view on the tensor and doesn't actually change it.

Comment: @DaVinci that it doesn't actually change the tensor is useful information that I didn't know, thanks. No particular reason really, but it seemed likely that something like this would have been possible with some option of `scan`. If that is not the case I guess I can simply wrap the flat-unflat operation into a function and use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how this kind of thing can be achieve using nested `theano.scan` calls.
In this example we add the number 3.141 to every element of a matrix, effectively simulating in a convoluted way the output of  `H + 3.141`:

```
H = T.dmatrix('H')
def fn2(col, row, matrix):
    return matrix[row, col] + 3.141

def fn(row, matrix):
    res, updates = theano.scan(fn=fn2,
                               sequences=T.arange(matrix.shape[1]),
                               non_sequences=[row, matrix])
    return res

results, updates = theano.scan(fn=fn,
                               sequences=T.arange(H.shape[0]),
                               non_sequences=[H])
f = theano.function([H], results)
f([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
# array([[ 3.141,  4.141],
#        [ 5.141,  6.141]])
```

As another example, let us add to each element of a matrix the product of its row and column indices:

```
H = T.dmatrix('H')
def fn2(col, row, matrix):
    return matrix[row, col] + row * col

def fn(row, matrix):
    res, updates = theano.scan(fn=fn2,
                               sequences=T.arange(matrix.shape[1]),
                               non_sequences=[row, matrix])
    return res

results, updates = theano.scan(fn=fn,
                               sequences=T.arange(H.shape[0]),
                               non_sequences=[H])
f = theano.function([H], results)
f(np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3))
# Out[2]:array([[  0.,   1.,   2.],
#               [  3.,   5.,   7.],
#               [  6.,   9.,  12.]])
```